# AVR with a lot of outputs

Tags: hardware

I'm searching for an ARV with a lot of outputs pins, it would me to create a custom led matrix. I searched on all famous ARV, but I didn't find one with more than 14 outputs. I don't care about input (while there is a serial bus like I2C or SPI…). Has someone a reference to tell me ?

Comment: ARV 
abbreviation for 
1. (Automotive Engineering) armed response vehicle ?

Comment: How many is "a lot"? 15? 150? 15,000?

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/732

Comment: How about 86? http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/atmega2560

Comment: 256? https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/power-architecture-processors/mpc5xxx-55xx-32-bit-mcus/mpc55xx-mcus/32-bit-mcu-for-automotive-powertrain-applications:MPC5566

Comment: There is only one vendor that makes AVR chips. Do you want us to go to their website product selector and click "sort by number of IOs" for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use shift registers. They can be daisy chained together to provide a large number of digital outputs while only utilizing 3-5 of your GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @RubberDuck’s answer, use a demux/decoder - such as [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs280c/schs280c.pdf).

Four inputs, sixteen outputs:

[image]